# How to change language and keep changed language for all sites?

Tags: javascript

I found a way to change the langauge:

```
<h2 class="fr_lang">Français</h2>
<h2 class="en_lang">English</h2>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

```
#lang-switch img {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all .5s;
  margin: auto 3px;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#lang-switch img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fr_lang,
.en_lang {
  display: none;
  transition: display .5s;
}

/* Language */
.active-lang {
  display: flex !important;
  transition: display .5s;
}

.active-flag {
  transition: all .5s;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // By default
  $('.en_lang').addClass("active-lang");
  $('#lang-switch .en').addClass("active-flag");

  // Function switch
  $(function() {
    // French button
    $("#lang-switch .fr").click(function() {
      // Enable French
      $('.fr_lang').addClass("active-lang"); 

      // Disable English
      $('.en_lang').removeClass("active-lang") 

      // Active or remove the opacity on the flags.
      $('#lang-switch .fr').addClass("active-flag");
      $('#lang-switch .en').removeClass("active-flag");
    });

    // English button
    $("#lang-switch .en").click(function() {

      // Enable English
      $('.en_lang').addClass("active-lang");

      // Disable French
      $('.fr_lang').removeClass("active-lang")

      // Active or remove the opacity on the flags.
      $('#lang-switch .en').addClass("active-flag");
      $('#lang-switch .fr').removeClass("active-flag");
    });
  });
});
```

This works find but my project includes many different sites.
How to keep the changed language for all sites/the hole project?

And is it possible to change the button text too? Or should I give the button the language class and create a new button with the other language class?

Thank you :)

Comment: Do your projects all run on the same domain?

Comment: Yes, only project is on another domain :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your sites run on the same domain you can use localStorage to store last language used.
Otherwise you will need a 'mediator' like a server to store the data.

Comment: Okey thank you, I will try to get more informations about how this works. :)